# Correct semantic html5

Tags: html5

I would be thankful for feedback for following html5 markup.
The outer div (class articles) has no more meaning as setting flex for it's child elements. Is a div the semantically correct choice in this case?

```css
.articles {
  display: flex;
}

.articles__article {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="articles">
    <article class="articles__article">     
      <h1 class="article__headline">Headline</h1>
      <p class="article__teaser">Text Text Text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="articles__article">     
      <h1 class="article__headline">Headline</h1>
      <p class="article__teaser">Text Text Text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="articles__article">     
     <img class="article__image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Why not just put the `article`s directly in the `main` and style that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case it is. As you stated yourself it has "no more meaning". It only exists for the purpose of styling.

This is what the MDN has to say about div:

> The HTML Content Division element () is the generic container for
>   flow content. It has no effect on the content or layout until styled
>   using CSS.
>
> As a "pure" container, the  element does not inherently represent
>   anything. Instead, it's used to group content so it can be easily
>   styled using the class or id attributes, marking a section of a
>   document as being written in a different language (using the lang
>   attribute), and so on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div